# Detect when JPanel moves

Tags: java, swing

I have a reference to a JPanel that is stored inside a JFrame. I tried attaching a ComponentAdaptor to the JPanel, but when I move the JFrame, it is not getting called. Any ideas on how I can detect when the JPanel moves on the screen if all I have is a reference to the JPanel and not the JFrame?

This is my adaptor:

```
private class Listener extends ComponentAdapter {

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        if (e.getComponent().equals(target)) {
            targetMoved();
        } else {
            stickyMoved();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you would want to see if the JFrame moved, as the JPanel isn't moving if it's still in the same location relative to it's parent container.

Comment: Agreed, but unfortunately all I have a reference to is the JPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [AncestorListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html) is what your looking for.

The JPanel does not move, but the frame that contains it does. You can use an `AncestorListener` on the panel, instead of `ComponentListener` to be notified when such events happen on any parent components.

```
private class Listener implements AncestorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void ancestorMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        if (e.getComponent().equals(target)) {
            targetMoved();
        } else {
            stickyMoved();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+, a single listener seems simpler than using two listeners.

Answer (score 2):

> how I can detect when the JPanel moves on the screen if all I have is a reference to the JPanel and not the JFrame?

You can get a reference to the JFrame by using:

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( panel );
```

Of course you won't know which frame until the panel has actually been added to the frame. You can use an `AncestorListener` as demonstrated in [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) to know when the panel is actually visible.

Then you can add your `ComponentListener` to the frame.

Comment: @user489041, it would seems to me that Andrei's approach would be simpler since you only need to use a single listener. In any case you should "accept" an answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused why you wouldn't just implement ancestorMoved since you already mentioned adding an AncestorListener and was afraid I missed something and was afraid I missed something. :)

Comment: @AndreiVajnaII, No you are not missing anything. Its me that was missing something. I've only ever used the AncestorListener once before (years ago) and forgot it also supported the AncestorMoved event. So I just relearned something, thanks  :)